# Badges and potential retire

Tags: discussion, badges

I see that the analytical badge is retired, would the precog badge be a retire target as well? It was only available to those involved back in area 51 days, correct?

Comment: Super User was never in Area 51 so that badge is not related, just there on the list

Comment: In a way, *Beta* could be considered retired. But it's obvious from the requirement that it won't be awarded anymore.

Comment: If a badge is retired, does it remove it from your list of achieved badges?

Comment: @CanadianLuke - I still have my analytical badge and that badge is now retired. I also believe that once you get a badge, you cannot lose it.

Comment: @CarlB Ahhh, I didn't know that badge got lost! I have it on this site LOL. But still, good to know